# Resize, crop and blurred edge in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

My original image has 3800x5700px I want to resize and crop to 550x550px, but the original image is in portrait mode, so I want to add a blurred border to complete the image, with the same image in question, but blurred

My code is

```
convert 2.jpg -resize '550x550>' -gravity center -quality 80 -extent 550x550 -background output.jpg
```

**Example of effect I desire**
[image]

**When I run the mentioned code the image is in desired dimensions but with white border, I wish the border blurred as in the example image**

[image]

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking why you're getting the white space on both sides? Or how to resize? or how to blur?

Comment: First image is landscape, so your image should be blurred on top and bottom since it is portrait?

Comment: What imagemagick version are you using? Where is the background image coming from? The first example it looks like the background is a different but similar photo. But if the person was in the middle you could blur the edges. You can not do that with your second example.

Comment: I rephrased the question in order to improve understanding

Answer (score 3):

`@Piro` is correct. Your first image is landscape and your second is portrait. So you need a different method for the portrait mode. Basically trim off the white, the resize it wider and blur the resized version. Then compose the trimmed image over the center of the blurred one.

In Imagemagick command line (unix syntax):

```
convert Cmz4y.jpg -fuzz 15% -trim +repage \
\( -clone 0 -resize 200x100% -blur 0x10 \) \
+swap -gravity center -compose over -composite \
result.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I need.

Comment: while running your example code the -extend option does not work. For the image to get the desired width I have to tinker with the resize values ​​in clone 0. Do you know any way for the -extent to work

Comment: -extend only pads with constant color, it does not expand the image.

Comment: I understand, but have some ways to resolve this problem of fixed width?

Comment: I do not understand what the question is about using -extent. Perhaps you should modify your post or post a new question about it.